# dose requirejs need all JS files to support AMD

Tags: requirejs, amd

i'm reading little about [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and trying to understand it.

What i want to know:

1. Should i structure my files in specific way or pattern like Module-Pattern ??
2. When working with libraries should these files support AMD ?

Thanks Alot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can structure your files any way you see fit. RequireJS [loads the script file](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) referenced in the `data-main` attribute of the script tag that loads require.js. From that file you're free to require whatever modules you want.
2. Libraries don't **need** to support AMD. You can use the [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to load modules that export value to the global scope (i.e. normal javascript files).

Comment: so just to get it clear. If i want to use for example any library that dose not support AMD or dose not implement the Module-Pattern only i need to use [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to be able to use them ??

Comment: Mostly yes. The non-AMD scripts will be attached to the global scope as they would without RequireJS. This means that they will work with both AMD modules and other libraries, but also that you don't get the "purity" of module patterns because the global (window) object is polluted. I use it and it works.

Comment: An exception would be a library that doesn't export just a single object. You can still use them with AMD if you use the shim exports callback function to wrap them to one export object. It's clunky though, but it's very rare for a library to work this way.

Comment: One last thing. what is shim exports callback function used for?

Comment: The callback (called "init" in the shim config) gets called when the module is resolved. Whatever you return from that function is what the module will return when you import it. See the docs I linked in the answer. I'm replying from my phone so it's not so easy to link right now :P

Answer (score 0):

Mostly I'm setting up a **require.js** project with a structure as below:

- root

  - js

    - modulesType1

      - mod1
      - mod2
    - modulesType2

      - mod1
      - mod2
    - app.js
    - bootstrap.js
  - lib

    - require

      - require.js
    - lib1

      - lib1.js
  - css/img/partials/...
  - index.html

And an initial **bootstrap.js** a have a `require.config` object and an initial `require`:

```
/*global define, require */

require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
      lib1: '../lib/lib1/lib1'
    },
    shim: {
      lib1: ['something']
    } 
});
require(['lib1', 'app'], function (lib1, app) {
   app.doSth();
});
```

In your html page you only need one `script` tag with a `data-main` attribute:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="js/bootstrap"></script>
</body>
```

**Edit:** modules don't have to be AMD compliant, but if they are under your own control, it is better to make them AMD compliant. You can make third party non-AMD libraries loadable using the [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) property in `require.config`.